# Double integral of a single variable function

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \right) g(x) dx$$

Can this integral be reduced to

$$  \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)dx $$

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No it cannot be reduced. $\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \Big)$ is a constant, let's say $k$, which reduces the integral to $k\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)dx $

However, this proves the following result:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \right) g(x) dx=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)dx \right)$$

Answer (score 19):

The expression $$\int_{\mathbb R} \left(\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)dx\right)g(x)dx$$

is a poorly written expression. It is not techincally wrong, but it is confusing. Following the strict definition of an integral, technically speaking, the expression equivalent to

$$\int_{\mathbb R} \left(\int_{\mathbb R} f(y)dy\right)g(x)dx$$

which converges if $$\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)dx$$ converges. This is because 
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \left(\int_{\mathbb R} f(y)dy\right)g(x)dx=\left(\int_{\mathbb R} f(y)dy\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)dx\right)$$

It is not equal to $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: In programming, one would call the $x$ from the $g$-integral within $\int_ℝ f(x)\:\mathrm{d}x$ a [shadowed variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing): the $x$ in $f(x)$ and the $x$ in $g(x)$ are actually two completely indepent variables which just happen to have the same name. $f(x)$ chooses the inner integral by convention, whereas $g(x)$ doesn't even see that one because it's hidden in the inner integral, and hence uses the outer variable $x$.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's a very good way to explain this to a large subgroup of users on this site (programmers with average math skills). Nicely done!

Comment: @leftaroundabout Would we be correct in assuming that using shadowed variables is considered bad practice in programming, just as it results in a poorly written expression here?

Comment: @Chessanator yes. Many compilers will give a warning when variables are shadowed, at least when compiling with `-Wall` or similar.

Comment: @5xum: Ouch!...

Comment: One difficulty is that $\int_R\left(\int_R f(x)dx\right)g(x)dx$ is just bad notation!  You need to use a different variable for each integral: $\int_R\left(\int f(x)dx\right) g(y) dy$.  Now, since each of f and g are functions of a single variable, and each integral is over all real numbers, not depending on either variable, that s the same as $\left(\int_R f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_R g(y) dy\right)$.

Answer (score 8):

No, in general
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \Big) g(x) dx\not=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)dx.$$
Take for example $f(x)=g(x)=x$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ and zero elsewhere. Then, by symmetry, the LHS is zero whereas the RHS is not zero.
However, if the integrals are convergent then, by linearity,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \Big) g(x) dx=\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \Big)\cdot\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}  g(x) dx\Big).$$