# Product of two integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, products, multiple-integral

From [How the product of two integrals is iterated integral? $\int\cdot \int = \iint$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549923/how-the-product-of-two-integrals-is-iterated-integral-int-cdot-int-iint) , the product of $\int f(x)\,dx$ and $\int g(y)\,dy$ is $\iint f(x)\,g(y)\,dx\,dy$.

From this, is the following true?

$$\left[\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx\right]\left[\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx\right] = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx\,dx$$

Please show your work so I can understand.

Comment: Did you mean to use the same variable of integration twice?

Comment: Also, are you only concerned about definite integration? Because I don’t think it would hold in general for indefinite integration.

Comment: Yes, the same variable is being used twice. I am only concerned about definite integration (both integrals are being integrated over the same interval.

It should say:

$\left[\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx\right]\left[\int_{a}^{b}g\left(x\right)dx\right] = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dxdx$

Comment: I found a post that says that if the integrals are convergent, then it is true.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333383/double-integral-of-a-single-variable-function

Answer (score 8):

In general no, the identity
$$
\left[\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx\right]\left[\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx\right] = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx\,dx
$$
does not hold. As a counterexample, take $a=-1$, $b=1$ and $f(x)=g(x)=x$. Then your identity says $0=4/3$.

By the way, there should be no circumstances under which you find yourself constrained to use the same dummy variable (here $x$) more than once as in $\mathrm d x \mathrm d x$ (that is unless you run out of letters) because it creates ambiguity for you and your readers.